# Can LCP and IPCP packets have different framing and byte-stuffing in PPP?

Tags: networking, protocols, network-protocols, ppp

I'm working on some middleware between a modem and a network stack doing PPP.  I'm having trouble with the initial configuration phase.  The endpoints exchange LCP packets with configuration requests and then acks, and then one of them begins with an IPCP configuration request; shortly afterwards one of them gives up.  Here's what I don't get:

The LCP packets use HDLC-like framing.  They start with 0x7E, the address follows with 0xFF, when the control byte 0x7D23 = 3 followed by byte-stuffed payload, checksum, and the frame character 0x7E.  These packets look something like this:

```
7EFF7D23C0217D217D207D207D347D227D267D207D2A7D207D207D257D267D2BE5E77D257D277D227D287D2295697E
```

The IPCP packets look totally different!  They still begin and end with 0x7E and have the HDLC checksum, but there is no address or control bytes, and there's *no* byte-stuffing.  These packets look like:

```
7E8021010000280206002D0F0103060000000081060000000082060000000083060000000084060000000079067E
```

Does this make sense?  Why do these packets look so different from each other?  Is something messed up here or is this typical?

Comment: Have you had a chance to run Wireshark on these packet captures? Is it any help?

Comment: @sarnold I don't have a debug port to hook Wireshark directly up to it, but I was able to dump the packets as you see them in the midst of a debug stream.  Then I wrote a python script to convert them to PCAP so I could load it into Wireshark.

It was while I was writing this script that I had to treat the two packets differently, just so Wireshark could read them; basically stripping off as much HDLC as is present.  It could be I just don't understand PCAP that well, though.

Comment: Anyway the upshot of that is that it's pretty much all configuration requests and acks, but it doesn't seem like the IPCP stuff is getting through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the LCP phase it's possible to negotiate "compression" options that'll get rid of the address and control fields. Take a look at [this link](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_PPPGeneralFrameFormat-4.htm).

Comment: Thank you.  It's been a while since I worked on that project but that's probably what was happening.